# Unable to upload images to Azure blob from HTML upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to save images that users upload via a webpage to Azure Storage as a blob. I have built the code and tested it out, I am connecting and creating the blob with no problems but it does not seem to be saving the file correctly as when I access the file via HTTP I just get the "Broken image" icon. If I download the file directly form the Azure Portal and try to open it in an image editor (paint) I get a message saying the file is not a valid bitmap file. You can see the file I just tried to upload at

https://gisstore01.blob.core.windows.net/ffinfofiles/Test/Core/Logo.jpg

and here is the code I am using to upload the files. I have no idea what is wrong here, any advice?

```
        var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());
        var BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("ffinfofiles");
        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName.ToLower());
        var BlobBlock = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName + FileExtension);
        BlobBlock.Properties.ContentType = UploadedFile.ContentType;

        using (UploadedFile.InputStream)
        {
            BlobBlock.UploadFromStream(UploadedFile.InputStream);
        }
```

O, this is an ASP.Net 4.6 application using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run a quick prototype and I managed to upload and download the image just fine, so I suspect your problem could be one of the following:

1)Blob containers don't allow public access by default. It may be that the image is stored fine at the moment, but your browser just doesn't have permission to see it. Have a look at your "ffinfofiles" blob container setting and make sure that "Public Read Access" is set to true

2)The information that you are using to set up the upload call is all dynamic so there is always the possibility that the data you are passing in as arguments is wrong. Double check that `UploadedFile.FileName.ToLower()` s correct ad more importantly that `UploadedFile.ContentType` is correct

3)Continuing the thought from item 2 above, you have to make sure that `UploadedFile.InputStream` is valid. Unless you are indeed streaming the file content from another source other than your local disk, I would actually just read the file bytes and use the BlobBlock.UploadFromByteArray() overload. Keep in mind that by doing this though you are effectively reading files into memory first, but it shouldn't be a problem if your files are small enough like a jpg in this case

Conclusion:

Here's the code I used as proof of concept.

```
var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());
var BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("ffinfofiles");
Container.CreateIfNotExists();

var BlobBlock = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
BlobBlock.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename));
BlobBlock.UploadFromByteArray(fileContent,0,fileContent.Length);
```

PS: To improve this further, consider using the Async overload, namely BlobBlock.UploadFromByteArrayAsync()

Comment: It looks like your taking the file directly off the HDD, did you try using an HTML upload form and get the same results? I checked the Permissions for the blobs and they are set to "Blob - Access Blobs via Anonymous requests". I don't have a "Public Read Access" permisions but there is a "Private" and that is NOT selected. I can't debug right now because VS 2015 has broken debugging for me but I know the variables are passing in right by looking at the blob name. From what I can tell it is not saving the actual data of the image.

Comment: I also don't want to first read files into memory before uploading as I am running in Azure WebSits and that has the potential to crash the site

Comment: I just did some more testing and hardcoded the BlobReference to "TestImage.jpg" and now when I pull up the image it is just a bunch of garbage (random letters/characters). I have even tried with a different image to make sure it was not the image so I am now convinced that the file content is not being saved correctly during the upload process. I will close this out and open a new problem when I get home from work

Comment: cool, well, ish! at least though now you know exactly where the problem is!  sorry I couldn't help you further with it, had a busy day, but I'll look out for your other post and try to help then if no one has already.

Comment: I have opened a new issue about the upload, hopfully you can figure out what the heck is going wrong here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733382/files-uploaded-to-azure-storage-are-corrupted